# R in batch mode

Tags: r

Is it necessary to have Rtools installed for running R in Batch mode, or is it fine if i just set up the environment variable for R.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need Rtools to *run* R, you only need Rtools to build R packages from source on the one platform that already gets them as binaries, ie Windows.

If you installed R on Windows the usual way, both `R.exe` and `Rscript.exe` will already be in your path.

Use `Rscript.exe` for batch processing / scripting of R, and see [previous questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Rscript) for more on `Rscript`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that I don't use Rtools when running R in batch mode on Windows Vista (because I've never specifically downloaded it).

You could set up the environment variable for R.exe and do it that way, or better yet, use [batchfiles](http://code.google.com/p/batchfiles/). I like the latter method because it always seems to point to the latest version of R on your computer which for me personally is very convenient and saves time.